# swift 3 fill dictionary programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, hashtag

I fill my parameters for an .post request like the following:

```
params = ["title":msgTitle.text ?? "",
"hashTags": [["name":"tag1"],["name":"HashTag"]]] as [String : Any]
```

As you can see hashTags are static. I need help understanding dictionaries. Is there a way to set hashTags via appending them to a dictionary? I want to be able to add multiple "name":"hashtagName" pairs.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, for example create the dictionary

```
var params: [String : Any] = ["title":msgTitle.text ?? ""]
```

then set the value for key `hashtags`

```
params["hashTags"] = [["name":"tag1"],["name":"HashTag"]]
```

---

Or via an array

```
var hashtags = [["name":"tag1"]]
hashtags.append(["name":"HashTag"])
params["hashTags"] = hashtags
```

---

Or the other way round:

```
var params: [String : Any] = ["hashTags" : [["name":"tag1"],["name":"HashTag"]]]
params["title"] = msgTitle.text ?? ""
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer with the array was perfect for my situation!